# Regarding how many hour we can access pre clearance at Dublin?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dublin, pre-clearance

I am travelling via Dublin ( Birmingham U.K. To Dublin and finally to Newark (USA). I have a booking for the lounge 51 as my flight has 4 hours stopover. How early can I go through preclearance?

Would they allow me as soon as I arrive Dublin which is 4 hours prior to my flight?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the [Preclearance Queue Time for Dublin Intl Airport](https://pqt.cbp.gov/report/DUB/03-20-2017) you will see the hours are 6:30am to 5pm. There's no other limitation.

Ps.: For the archives, this link will break once the report expires, then you need to visit https://pqt.cbp.gov and manually set the airport and date.